# How to change container name automatically when increase pods

Tags: kubernetes

With the below yaml file I am creating two pod with two different environment containers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: tomcat-ns
  labels:
    name: tomcat-ns
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace : tomcat-ns
  name: petstore-deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat-container1
        image: petstore_demo:latest  
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: PetStore1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace : tomcat-ns
  name: petstore-deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat-container2
        image: petstore_demo:latest  
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: PetStore2

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace : tomcat-ns
  name: tomcat-service-1
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 81
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

But every time I need more than one container, I have to create a new pod and rename the container in it.

**I Expected**
I have already given the name tomcat-container1 to the container in the pod, i.e. if I give 3 instead of replicas-1, then 3 containers tomcat-container1, tomcat-container2 and tomcat-container3 should be created.

**Note**:
If I increase the replicas, The container name will automatically be created, but when I recreate the pod repeatedly, it will get a different name each time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have already given the name tomcat-container1 to the container in the pod, i.e. if I give 3 instead of replicas-1, then 3 containers tomcat-container1, tomcat-container2 and tomcat-container3 should be created.

You cannot do that in Kubernetes. The pods of the replicas will be **identical**, because they are created from the *template* in the `Deployment`. That is why you cannot dynamically change the container names of the replica pods.

Comment: Hi @Jonas.. What should we do if we maximize the creation of the container so that the container name is automatically created next to the name we have given

Answer (score 0):

The container name is local to a Pod.  You don't need to give containers unique names across Deployments.  In your example, I'd just name all of the containers `tomcat`.

Considering a smaller example:

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: docker.io/library/tomcat:latest
```

you will get three identical Pods named something like `your-deployment-12345-abcde`, `your-deployment-12345-fghij`, and `your-deployment-12345-klmno`.  If you `kubectl get pod -o yaml` then you will see that all of them have the same container names.  That's not a problem.  Even in your example where the Pods come from different Deployments, it's still not a problem.

In the unusual event you have direct login access to the Nodes and you can run commands like `docker ps` there, one thing you will see is that the Kubernetes per-pod per-container names are not the same as the Docker (or other container runtime) container names, which might be a source of confusion here.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, when you increase the number of replicas for a Deployment, it does indeed create multiple pods with the same container specifications. However, it appends a unique identifier to the pod's name, so each pod gets a different name but retains the same container name you've specified. This is by design to ensure uniqueness and distinguish between individual pods.

For example, if you set replicas to 3 for "petstore-deployment-1", you will get three pods named like this:

1. petstore-deployment-1-XXXXX (where XXXXX is a unique identifier)
2. petstore-deployment-1-YYYYY
3. petstore-deployment-1-ZZZZZ
   All three of these pods will have a container named "tomcat-container1," and you can access them using the unique pod names if needed.

This behavior is typical in Kubernetes to maintain pod uniqueness and manage scaling efficiently. You can refer to these pods by their individual names if necessary, and the container name remains consistent.

Answer (score 0):

A Kubernetes deployment could have multiple-containers Pods template and by that you can define specific names for them as well as defining particular env variables.
E.g:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-ns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat-container1
        image: petstore_demo:latest  
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: PetStore1
      - name: tomcat-container2
        image: petstore_demo:latest  
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: PetStore2
```

But without details of you purpose it's difficult to say, is't a good way or not. So, I guess you aware of what you do ;)